# spring tool suite not working with java 8

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I just downloaded Spring tool Suite 3.9 but it is not working with java 8 and wants java 6. Do you know a way to open it with java 8? And please let me know if there is a better free IDE for spring on mac.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as per sts documentation . 
https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html

Answer (score 0):

STS doesn't need a JDK6 to run, it requires a JDK8 instead, so you need to have a full JDK8 installed. STS picks that up automatically while launching.

In case of doubt, you can specify the JVM to run STS with in the sts.ini file in the same way than you can specify the JVM for Eclipse in the eclipse.ini: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

In case this doesn't work, please add additional details about the exact message that you see, when you see it, and what version of macOS you are running. It would also be interesting to see if plain Eclipse behaves the same.